# Excel - Create list of unique values with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtering

In worksheet 1, master_data, I have a table with 30,000 or so player records.

In worksheet 2, Player Look Up, I am attempting to create a lookup with helpers.
Players appear several hundred times in the master_data sheet and I would like to list only unique values of any particular player's position (master_data H2:H30000).

The criteria would be:
Player Look Up B1 (Name) matching master_data F2:F30000 (Player_Name)
Player Look Up B3 (Year) being part of a variable formula that is run against master_data B2:B30000.

This variable formula would allow be to select from a list in B3 which contains year values (2015,2016,2017,2018 or All) and return only records that meet that year criteria.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a Pivot table for this.

Comment: I think you should concatenate columns to a create column with unique values in each worksheet, then run vlookup()